# Building application, but want to know if there's any way to store variables between runs of the program?

Tags: python

I'm making a program and with items and definitions for each item. This program should rack up words over time, but I'm wondering if there's any way to keep the words stored with their properties between program runs (closing and opening the program).
Here's my item class:

```
class Item: 
    def __init__(self, item_name, item_definition):
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.item_definition = item_definition
        self.item_level = 0
        self.date_to_review = 0 #implement hour scale in py for this, should be 4 hours, since items added will be in apprentice 1.
    
    def __lt__(self, otherItem):
        return self.item_name < self.otherItem.item_name
    def __gt__(self, otherItem):
        return self.item_name > self.otherItem.item_name
    def __le__(self, otherItem):
        return self.item_name <= self.otherItem.item_name
    def __ge__(self, otherItem):
        return self.item_name >= self.otherItem.item_name
    def __ne__(self, otherItem):
        return self.item_name != self.otherItem.item_name
    def __eg__(self, otherItem):
        return self.item_name == self.otherItem.item_name
```

It's not very complicated but I wanted it so that when I open the program back up I can still have each item with it's name, definitions, and level on it.
I was wondering if there's any way to do this? I was thinking about switching to Java for this since I saw that Java has something similar to what I need in `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`, but I'd really rather prefer writing in Python, as I vastly prefer tkinter to JavaSwing

Thanks

Comment: Simplest would be to store them in a text file.

Comment: You write the state to file, then read the file when the program starts. Every programming language that has any practical use is capable of doing this; including Python.

Comment: @JohnGordon How would I go about storing the definition, item, and it's level in a text file?

Comment: @Carcigenicate same as above.

Comment: How about the pickle module. Its the best for storing objects:https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: Just extract the data out of the instance like you would anywhere else, and then write it as JSON, or just a row of a CSV file, or something similar. This is called "serialization", and if you search for that, you'll find many ways and explanations.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Alright, thank you. This is my first time attempting a program of this scale. I'll try and use the pickle module that the person above posted. My question now is would a regular text file work to dump things into or does it have to be a JSON?

Comment: @TheTridentGuy Thank you very much, I will try this. My question now is would a regular text file work to dump things into or does it have to be a JSON or another type of file?

Comment: the `pickle` module will take any file. *Remember: file extensions do not affect what you can put in the file. You could store an image in a ".txt" file or vice versa. The file extension only helps applications recognize file types. Note that storing an image in a ".txt" file will result in a random array of characters, as images are binary files.*

Comment: A file JSON is a regular text file. It's just a specific, common format for storing data. Nowadays, most languages can read JSON, so it's a very portable format to store data in. You can store data however you like though. You're just responsible for serializing/deserializing it if you don't use a common format.